# SQL Server update value in another table if value in (inserted) first table is greater

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following tables: (simplified for clarity)

1. AppWorkHeader with columns: (ProjectID **(FK)**, ProgPercent, + 40 others not relevant)
2. AppProjects with columns: (ProjectID **(PK)**, ProgPercent + 9 others not relevant)

I am trying to create a trigger that after insert, the ProgPercent value from the AppWorkHeader table updates the ProgPercent value in the AppProjects table only if it's greater than the existing value. I can get it to work with single insertions with the following:

```
-- Only works on single row insert
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AppWorkHeader_project_trigger]
ON 
[dbo].[AppWorkHeader]
AFTER INSERT AS
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RETURN

SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Get the current project completion percentage from the AppProjects table
DECLARE @inserted_projectID int = (SELECT i.ProjectID FROM inserted i)
DECLARE @current_percent decimal(5,4) = (SELECT ProgPercent FROM AppProjects WHERE ProjectID = @inserted_projectID)

UPDATE AppProjects
SET ProgPercent = inserted.ProgPercent
FROM inserted
WHERE AppProjects.ProjectID = inserted.ProjectID AND inserted.ProgPercent > @current_percent
```

I can get multiple insertions to work with the following code. However, the greater-than part of my where clause seems to be ignored. Multiple insertions with the same ProjectID are updated to lower values.

```
-- Multiple row insert
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AppWorkHeader_project_trigger]
ON 
[dbo].[AppWorkHeader]
AFTER INSERT AS

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RETURN

SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE AppProjects
SET ProgPercent = inserted.ProgPercent
FROM inserted
WHERE AppProjects.ProjectID = inserted.ProjectID AND inserted.ProgPercent > (SELECT ProgPercent FROM AppProjects WHERE ProjectID = (SELECT inserted.ProjectID))
```

I can't figure out how to get the existing value in the AppProjects table without using a variable, and I can't seem to get multiple insertions to work if I use a variable. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each inserted `ProjectID` find the maximum `ProgPercent` (if there are several rows inserted with the same `ProjectID`).
Then join table with new values to the table with old values.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AppWorkHeader_project_trigger]
    ON [dbo].[AppWorkHeader]
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH
    CTE_InsertedProjects
    AS
    (
        SELECT
            inserted.ProjectID
            ,MAX(inserted.ProgPercent) AS MaxProgPercent
        FROM inserted
        GROUP BY inserted.ProjectID
    )
    ,CTE_AllProjects
    AS
    (
        SELECT
            AppProjects.ProjectID
            ,AppProjects.ProgPercent AS OldProgPercent
            ,CTE_InsertedProjects.MaxProgPercent AS NewProgPercent
        FROM
            AppProjects
            INNER JOIN CTE_InsertedProjects ON CTE_InsertedProjects.ProjectID = AppProjects.ProjectID
        WHERE
            CTE_InsertedProjects.MaxProgPercent > AppProjects.ProgPercent
    )
    UPDATE CTE_AllProjects
    SET OldProgPercent = NewProgPercent;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

While Tring to Update Use JOIN To match the column ProjectID  from AppProjects on AppWorkHeader ..

```
Update AP
set AP.ProgPercent=AWH.ProgPercent
FROM AppProjects AP Left JOIN AppWorkHeader AWH on  AP.ProjectID=AWH.ProjectID
Where AP.ProgPercent < AWH.ProgPercent
```

This will only Update those rows where ProgPercent in AppProjects is Lesser than ProgPercent in AppWorkHeader

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce the desired results. Bulk inserting multiple rows with common ProjectID's (1, 2, 3, 4) and random ProgPercent doesn't always update the AppProjects table with the highest value. It appears to be different every time actually. Sometimes the highest value is there, sometimes the lowest. Seems random, or an order problem.